# Subrelatório no ireport

Tags: java, ireport

Estou tentando fazer um relatório onde cada código tem x clientes. Exemplo

Código 1:

```
Bruno
Rodrigo
Fernando
```

Código 2:

```
Rafael
João
```

Eu recupero esses códigos de um banco de dados, exemplo:

```
1 Bruno
1 Rodrigo
1 Fernando
2 Rafael
2 João
```

Como podem ver os códigos se repetem, dessa forma quando gero o meu relatório que contem um sub relatório toda essa quantidade é repetida e o relatório fica enorme.

Resumindo, como conseguiria deixar esse relatório como o primeiro exemplo apresentado?

```
public void gerarRelatorio(List<PreEmissao> lista, String contrato) throws JRException {
        Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        /**Parametros, essa lista é o DataSource do sub relatório*/
        parametros.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", "src/main/resources/Report/Faturamento_subreport.jasper");
        parametros.put("lista", lista);

        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager
                .compileReport(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Report/Faturamento.jrxml"));

        /**Essa lista que é passada carrega o DataSorce do relatório principal, dela eu só pego o código*/
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parametros,
                new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lista));

        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, "D:/Ouvidoria/Relatorio" + contrato + ".pdf");

        System.out.println("Relatório gerado.");

    }
```

Comment: Você quer agrupar por código? Consegue incluir a imagem de como está atualmente e o resultado esperado?

Comment: O relatório ficou muito grande @BrunoCésar, seria basicamente isso, exibir os Clientes de acordo com o código.

Comment: Quando ele é gerado ele exibe código 1 e no sub relatório todos os dados são exibidos

Comment: Por exemplo, se eu tenho 5 registros com o código 1 ele gera um sub relatório pra cada registro que tem o código 1, o objetivo é gerar apenas 1 que contenha todos os clientes que possuem o código igual a 1

Comment: Resolvi o problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resolvido, adicionei um `Report Group` agrupando pelo código no relatório e nem precisou de um sub relatório.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ok. Então se essa foi sua resposta, e o recurso Report Group foi sua saída, marque sua resposta como aceita.

Comment: Sim eu marcarei como correta, porém de acordo com as regras do site só posso marcar minha resposta como correta após 2 (dois) dias.